# element id is not accessible javascript

Tags: javascript

i have the following code. here i am declaring all the element id's to variables as global before all the functions declared. but those variables are taken by the functions
below is the sample:

```
var ddlpf=document.getElementById('<%=ddlpf.ClientID%>');  
var disp_msg=document.getElementById('<%=disp_msg.ClientID%>');  
function btn_proceed_Click()  
{  
   var ses='<%=Session("hcur").toString %>';  
   if(pos_valid()==true)  
   alert('success');  
}

function pos_valid()  
{  
   var pos_valid=false;  
   var ses;  
   var ccy;  
   var ccy1;  
   var ccy2;  
   var as11costbud;  
   ses='<%=Session("hcur").toString %>';  
   var bm='<%=Session("benchmark").toString %>';  
   var dtsheet='<%=Session("dtsheet").toString %>';  
   var ratedis='<%=Session("ratedis").toString %>';  
   if(ddlpf.selectedIndex <= 0)  
   {  
       message("Please select the Portfolio");  
       return;  
   }  
   pos_valid=true;  
   return pos_valid;
```

}

```
function message(msg)  
{  
    disp_msg.innerHTML=msg;  
    var modalPopupBehaviorCtrl = $find('modalpop');              
    modalPopupBehaviorCtrl.set_PopupControlID("poppan");    
    modalPopupBehaviorCtrl.show();   
}
```

If i declare the variable "ddlpf" inside the pos_valid() and "disp_masg" inside the message(), it works.
the code is like this:

```
function pos_valid()      
{        
    var ddlpf=document.getElementById('<%=ddlpf.ClientID%>');      
    //code    
}

function message()       
{    
    var disp_msg=document.getElementById('<%=disp_msg.ClientID%>');     
    //code    
}
```

but these id's are common to 5 functions. not only this two. i have 20 id's which are common to 5 big functions. thats why i have declared them outside the functions.

what change should i make?

Comment: ddlpf and disp_msg is not working inside pos_valid and message functions

Comment: Why are you using strange IDs?

Comment: actually i am having additional 4 functions which are using those id's

Comment: i am having 5 big functions which are using same repeated id's. thats why i want to declare them as global variable so that i could access them in all the functions and no need to declare them again and again

Comment: Have you checked the console, there might be some error messages? Notice, that if you declare the globals before involved elements exist, variables are not updated automatically later. To answer your "question", we need more information: What you expect to happen? What happens instead expected results? How have you placed your scripts to the page?

Comment: i have placed the script on the top of the page. btn_proceed_click is the button-click event. pos_valid is the validation for some dropdowns

Comment: problem is, i have placed the script on the top now placed it at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are putting the script at the top of the HTML page. So the page has not finished loading yet and you are trying to access the `document.getElementById` even before the document.body is ready. So when you access them in your functions, the variables value will be `undefined` => your problem

Try it this way,

```
var ddlpf;  
var disp_msg;  

window.onload = function(){
    ddlpf=document.getElementById('<%=ddlpf.ClientID%>');  
    disp_msg=document.getElementById('<%=disp_msg.ClientID%>');  
}
```

This way, you can put the code anywhere.

Comment: yeah aravind , now i put the same code at the bottom . it works. i appreciate ur help

Comment: @Soombinakundi If aravind gave the answer please accept it so that others will not try to answer your already solved question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understood your question and with the code provided you are wondering

- why your global variables appear not to work `ddlpf and disp_msg is not working inside pos_valid and message functions`

You have to make sure that the global variables are declared before any function is using them. Another option would be to pass in the variables.

In my **[demo on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HCkKF/)** you can see that it works. This html

```
<h2>Element id is not accessible</h2>

<select id="ddlpf">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<button onclick=btn_proceed_Click()>proceed</button>
<div id="disp_msg">

</div>
```

and this javascript

```
var ddlpf=document.getElementById('ddlpf');  
var disp_msg=document.getElementById('disp_msg');  
function btn_proceed_Click()  
{     
   if(pos_valid()==true)  
   {
       var btn = document.getElementById('btn');  
       btn.innerHTML='success';  
   };
}

function pos_valid()  
{  
   var pos_valid=false;  
   var ses, ccy, ccy1, ccy2, as11costbud;  
   var selectedIndex = ddlpf.selectedIndex
   if(selectedIndex <= 0)  
   {  
     message("Please select the Portfolio. Your selection:" + selectedIndex);  
       return;  
   }  
  message("Your selection" + selectedIndex);  
   pos_valid=true;  
   return pos_valid;  
}

function message(msg)  
{  
    disp_msg.innerHTML=msg;  
}
```

If you provide more information `erromessages from chrome dev tools` we can help better.

Comment: thanks. i have placed the script at the top of the page. now i changed my code according to aravind's idea. it works. i appreciate your help too